# How to fix html2pdf.js creating speed issue?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, electron

Now I develop a barcode generator app.

Here I used [html2pdf.js](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf)

I used `settimeout` for bulk save.

But when I input 13 barcodes and 358 barcodes, the rendering speed is different

> 13 barcodes : average 280ms
>
> 358 barcodes : average 6500ms

**in case of 13 barcodes**

[image: 13 barcodes]

**in case of 358 barcodes**

[image: 358 barcodes]

And my code is below

```
async function timerCallback(){
        var elem = $('#'+elemlist[elemindex]);
        var index = elem.attr('id');
        var value = elem.attr('value');
        console.log(index,value);
        var svgelem = document.getElementById(index);
        var html = svgelem.outerHTML;
        var path = dir+"/"+bar_type+"_"+value+".pdf";
        console.log(path);

        modal.updateModal(elemindex);
        var opt = {
            margin:       0,
            filename:     bar_type+"_"+value+".pdf",
            image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas:  { scale: 30 },
            jsPDF:        { orientation : 'l', unit: 'px', format: [$('#'+index).width(), $('#'+index).height()+10]}
        };

        // New Promise-based usage:
        var worker = new html2pdf();
        await worker.set(opt).from(html).outputPdf().then(async function(e){
            var buf = new Buffer(e, 'binary');
            await fs.writeFile(path, buf, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }

                console.log("The file was saved!");
            }); 
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(elemindex<elemlist.length)
            {
                timerCallback();
                elemindex++;
            }
            else{
                modal.removeModal();
            }
        }, 1300);
    }

    timerCallback();
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: My guess is because of async/await construct you are having speed issue.

Comment: Thanks for your watching.
By the way, why `async/await` made such issue?

Comment: Async/await makes the code flow synchronous/blocking. Non-blocking/asynchronous should make your code faster.

Comment: then how can I do it?

Comment: I agree with @Rafiek , try without `async/await`

Comment: hi, I found the reason and `async/await` have no relation with this issue.

Comment: I am interested! Can you post your own answer?

Comment: @Jin What was the cause of slowness ?